# Stress test our store's checkout process

Tags: e-commerce, stress-testing

I want to simulate our whole checkout process under load.  This essentially involves running a number of POSTs in sequence, where the client is storing a unique cookie for each sequence that allows the session to be preserved.  Can anyone recommend a software or service that meets these conditions?

Comment: This may depend upon language / environment.  At my job, we use TFS/Visual Studio so we use Microsoft's Load Testing framework. What language is the application written in and what type of servers do you have?

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing could be very easily, effectively and freely accomplished using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). You can either record the journey using JMeter's proxy or simply add the requests manually.

To simulate cookies add a [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to the testplan. For any other tokens or session ids that need to be correlated you can use a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options for this kind of test. Free/open-source tools will require a bit more work on your part but are otherwise free. Tools like ours ([Load Tester 5](http://www.webperformance.com/)) will get the job done much quicker, but there is a cost for the software. If your organization does not have much experience with load testing and are on a tight schedule, you might want to bring in outside help to help you meet your deadline and learn the process (we offer services as well!).